# How to install postgresql on Ubuntu 16.04 VM despite "unmet dependencies" to set up Ruby on Rails project

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox VM using Vagrant. 
Windows 10 host. 
Git Bash terminal.

Connected to vagrant up, vagrant ssh.

I have a fresh VM and have installed ruby and rails. I am trying to install postgresql to use for a Ruby on Rails project, but I get the following error:

> vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.6 but it is not going to be installed
>    postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-9.6 but it is not going to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I've tried various things, and nothing seems to let me install postgres

Comment: just small question - did you "sudo apt-get update" + "sudo apt-get upgrade" after creating VM? I presume you have some old downloaded ISO? By the way I see in your output "vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64" - I see "trusty" there - are you sure you use Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes I have run the update and upgrade before with no change in the problem. I installed trusty-64 according to these instructions for a vagrant/virtualbox installation: 

http://itzedu.github.io/ 

and installed ruby and rails using these follow up instructions: 

http://itzedu.github.io/two.html 

trusty64 seems to be fine. is there a particular issue i should check for? 

thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu "trusty" should be 14.04 - try `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/*relea*` to see a version. To install pg 9.6 on ubuntu/debian I followed this - https://raonyguimaraes.com/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-ubuntudebianlinux-mint/ - just use proper repo in list - this is why you need to be sure about version you run.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem in my ubuntu 16.04

but i fixed that problem and it's very simple just follow these step and you will be able to install postgresql 10 in your system :

Add this to your sources.list:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
```

after that add these link to your `pgdg.list` file if it's not there you have to create and add link and save it.

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

then update your system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and install that unmet dependencies :

```
apt-get install ssl-cert
```

that's it. now Install `postgresql` using these command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
```

Comment: Avoid extra spaces between lines and only mark you code under `code` by selecting the code and hitting Ctrl+K or pressing the `code` sign above.

Answer (score 0):

@JosMac pointed out that I am running Ubuntu 14.04 instead of 16.04 as I had thought.

I was still running into similar errors, but I just ended up installing the rails-dev-box (https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box) way which uses yakkety64, and seems to work.